# Array object existence on the heap

Tags: arrays, object

If a class has an array as its member and if an object of the class is created then where does that array object live. I mean the object of the class stays on the heap, so does that array object stay as an object within that class' object or it has an independent existence on the heap with some sort of link with the class' object.

Comment: It entirely depends on the programming language. Perhaps you'd like to specify.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're talking about where in memory things are located, as well as objects, I'm going to guess you mean C++. If that's not true, as Matt said, it might help to specify in your question so someone who knows about the language you're using can answer :).

In C++, whether a member array is placed inside the object's memory, or separately on the heap, depends on how the array is declared: static member arrays will be placed inside the object, while dynamic member arrays will exist in new heap memory.

---

If you declare the array statically:

```
class MyStaticArrayClass
{
    int myArray[10];
    // ...
};
```

If you declare a MyStaticArrayClass object, the array will be inside the MyStaticArrayClass object itself. That is, if you declare your object on the stack:

```
MyStaticArrayClass myObject;
```

The contents of myArray will also be on the stack, while if you declare your object on the heap:

```
MyStaticArrayClass * myObjectPtr = new MyStaticArrayClass;
```

Then the contents of myArray will be on the heap, but inside the memory pointed to by myObjectPtr (the default destructor for MyStaticArrayClass will take care of deallocating this memory for you when you call delete myObjectPtr;).

---

If you declare the array dynamically:

```
class MyDynamicArrayClass
{
    int * myArray;
    // constructor initializes to myArray = new int[10];
    // ...
};
```

If you declare a MyDynamicArrayClass object, the array will be on the heap, external to the MyDynamicArrayClass object itself. (You would need to write a custom destructor to call delete [] myArray).